# What are the requirements for a schengen visa to Germany from Cyprus?

Tags: schengen-visas, cyprus

If you are a Zimbabwean studying in Cyprus, what are the requirements for a Schengen visa to Germany, and are you able to apply in Cyprus?

Comment: It's the same as if you applied from anywhere else.

Comment: I presume you are in the Republic of Cyprus. Being a legal resident in an EU country will greatly help with your application, but you still have to supply all the usual documents.

Answer (score 3):

For a short-stay Schengen Visa (tourist or business), you would apply at the German Embassy. Longterm national visas for Germany (e.g. students, work or family unification) can only be applied for at the German Missions in Turkey.

[Embassy of the Federal Republic of Germany](http://www.nikosia.diplo.de/Vertretung/nikosia/en/Startseite.html)
10 Nikitaras Str.
1080 Nicosia
P.O. Box 25705
1311 Nicosia
Tel.: 22 45 11 45
Fax: 22 66 56 94
www.nikosia.diplo.de

> Visa applications can be submitted at the German Embassy Monday-Thursday, 09:00-11:00 am. Friday closed.
>
> The following documents should be submitted in original plus one photocopy:
>
> - 1 recent photograph (full frontal picture, light background, size of face min. 34 mm, no tinted glasses)
> - passport with at least two blank pages, the validity date of which must exceed the visa’s validity for at least three months, and which may not be older than 10 years at the expiry of the visa
> - the Alien Registration Card of the Republic of Cyprus (ARC) as well as the Temporary Resident Permit (TRP, also called „Pink Paper"), the validity date of which must exceed the visa’s validity for at least three months
> - proof of valid individual or group travel health insurance to cover any expenses which might arise in connection with repatriation for medical reasons, urgent medical attention and/or emergency hospital treatment and valid throughout the territory of the Member States applying in full the provisions of the Schengen acquis and cover the entire period of the person’s stay. The minimum coverage shall be EUR 30.000,-.
> - proof of sufficient financial funds (e.g. bank statements of the last 6 months, bank letter, information on salary, or declaration of support of the host)
> - proof of the applicant’s employment/educational and/or residential situation in Cyprus
> - invitation letters
> - declaration of support of the host (in case sufficient funds are not proven by applicant), according to Section 66-68 Aliens' Act
> - registration of the company; letter from the employer in Cyprus stating position in company and reasons for travel
> - proof of accommodation in case of tourist visa (e.g. hotel voucher)
>     flight reservation
> - for students: results of studies in Cyprus of the past semesters (transcript)
>     Visa applications through the Visa Information System (VIS)
>
> On November 20, 2015 the German Embassy Nicosia introduced the [Visa Information System (VIS),](https://videx.diplo.de/videx/;jsessionid=5LtYZlBu88fusSngRDSnMP2P.undefined?0) that means that for visa applications the applicant's biometric data (10-digit-finger-scans) is collected.
>
> The visa procedure takes at least 10 days. Please book your flight and hotel reservations accordingly. Please refrain from any inquiries regarding the application status in this period.